# Compiling Vue.js component while rendering Laravel Blade partial view

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js

I have a simple component in Vue.js which is used in a partial view - **question.blade.php**:

```
{{--HTML code--}}

<my-component type='question'>
    <div class="question">[Very long text content...]</div>
</my-component>

{{--more HTML code--}}
```

The idea behind the component is to create a "show more - show less" logic around the question content.

The component is compiled and renders just fine on page load. However, there are cases where I need to dynamically load a question **via Ajax**. For this, I make a simple jQuery Ajax call, retrieve the HTML of the question.blade.php and append it in the DOM. The problem is, **the component is not compiled**.

**How do I make sure the component is always compiled when the partial view gets rendered, independently of whether it occurs on page load or via Ajax call?**

*Full component code:*

```
{% verbatim %}
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-bind:class="cssClasses" v-html="content"></div>

        <div v-if="activateShowMore && !isShown" class="sml-button closed" v-on:click="toggleButton()">
            <span class="sml-ellipsis">...</span><span class="sml-label">{{$t('show_more')}}</span>
        </div>
        <div v-if="activateShowMore && isShown" class="sml-button open" v-on:click="toggleButton()">
            <span class="sml-label">{{$t('show_less')}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
    /*styles*/
</style>

<script type="text/babel">
    export default {
        props: ['content', 'type'],

        data() {
            return {
                activateShowMore: false,
                isShown: false,
                cssClasses: this.getCssClasses()
            }
        },

        locales: {
            en: {
                'show_more': 'show more',
                'show_less': 'show less'
            },
            de: {
                'show_more': 'mehr anzeigen',
                'show_less': 'weniger anzeigen'
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.checkShowMore();
        },

        watch: {
            isShown: function(shouldBeShown) {
                this.cssClasses = this.getCssClasses(shouldBeShown);
            }
        },

        methods: {
            checkShowMore: function() {
                let $element = $(this.$el);
                let visibleHeight = $element.outerHeight();
                let realHeight = $element.find('.text-area-read').first().outerHeight();
                let maxHeight = this.getMaxHeight();

                this.activateShowMore = (visibleHeight === maxHeight) && (visibleHeight < realHeight);
            },
            getMaxHeight: function() {
                switch (this.type) {
                    case 'question':
                        return 105;
                    case 'answer':
                        return 64;
                }
            },
            toggleButton: function() {
                this.isShown = !this.isShown;
            },
            getCssClasses: function(shouldBeShown) {
                if (undefined === shouldBeShown || !shouldBeShown) {
                    return 'sml-container' + ' sml-' + this.type + ' sml-max-height';
                }

                return 'sml-container' + ' sml-' + this.type;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: php is for server, try to use html

Comment: is the vue component dependent on the results from the ajax call? if yes! how are you sending that data to vue then.

Comment: @zeidanbm The idea behind the component is to create a "show more - show less" logic around the question text. So, every time I make an Ajax call to retrieve a question, I need the "show more" component to work with its text content.

Comment: so pretty much you need to notify your component of the update in the DOM. I would rather just pull all the logic into vue and do the http request inside. But you might be able to use events here. can you please post your vue component code?

Comment: @zeidanbm Updated the post. The problem is, I'm working on a legacy codebase and the Ajax calls to retrieve the questions are done via jQuery from another script. The "show more" Vue.js component is new.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best way but it should do the trick. But I had to deal with vue and jquery communication before.

What I did is created a hidden input and changed the value with jquery after the ajax call finished and then triggered the change event with jquery. Then you already listening to the event inside vue and you will know you need to update the content. This should get you going with some modification to your vue component and should be able to update. If you need to send the content to vue you might need to send it in the input hidden value. I did a quick demo code to explain what I mean. Here's the [link](https://codepen.io/zeidanbm/pen/LzKRwj).

```
var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data(){
            return{
              content: 'hi there',
            }
          },
          methods: {
            onChangeHandler: function(e){
              this.content = e.target.value
            }
          },
       });

       $('#me').on('click',function(){
         $('#update').val('Good Day!')
         $('#update').trigger("click")
      });
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I've been thinking about a solution similar to this one. I will surely end up doing something like this.